# How to add backdrop images for py nodes?

Tags: python, pynodes

When creating a custom Node - tree type (not scene/material/texture) is it possible to have a background image defined? This would be similar to how the compositing nodes allow an image backdrop, but instead, for a custom tree type.

Comment: Ok I've added a clarification, hope that helps.

Comment: Why doesn't using the viewer node work? (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+click)

Comment: I'm making my own custom node tree - there is no viewer node so far, and I'm looking to add an image into the background of the node itself, similar to how e.g. image texture or render layer nodes look like in the compositor.

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Sadly I don't know how to do that. Can you look at the source for the other nodes that do that?

Comment: @BassamKurdali are you still looking for this?

Comment: yes, I think I'll try an experiment with bpy.utils.previews ; still have to figure out if/how to make the previews big though.

Answer (score 3):

well, either way I took this as a challenge. 
[image]

With any luck by including the code, it will anger someone into making a much more elegant solution. (if the `from bgl import *` bothers you importing as you need is probably tidier. But adding `bgl.` infront of everything gets on my nerves.

You'll notice it looks for the Sverchok custom tree, changing it to your own should be zero work.

```
# ##### BEGIN GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#  modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
#  as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
#  of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
#  Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
#
# ##### END GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####

import time
import bpy
import bgl
from bgl import *
from bpy.types import SpaceNodeEditor

from sverchok import node_tree
from sverchok.node_tree import SverchCustomTree
from sverchok.node_tree import SverchCustomTreeNode

callback_dict = {}
point_dict = {}


def node_id(oper):
    return str(hash(oper) ^ hash(time.monotonic()))


def tag_redraw_all_nodeviews():
    for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
        areas = window.screen.areas
        for area in (a for a in areas if a.type == 'NODE_EDITOR'):
            for region in (r for r in area.regions if r.type == 'WINDOW'):
                region.tag_redraw()


def callback_enable(n_id, nt):
    global callback_dict
    if n_id in callback_dict:
        return

    data = {}
    data['tree_name'] = nt.name
    args = n_id, data

    handle_pixel = SpaceNodeEditor.draw_handler_add(draw_callback_px, args, 'WINDOW', 'PRE_VIEW')
    callback_dict[n_id] = handle_pixel
    tag_redraw_all_nodeviews()


def callback_disable(n_id):
    global callback_dict
    handle_pixel = callback_dict.get(n_id, None)
    if not handle_pixel:
        return
    SpaceNodeEditor.draw_handler_remove(handle_pixel, 'WINDOW')
    del callback_dict[n_id]
    tag_redraw_all_nodeviews()


def callback_disable_all():
    global callback_dict
    temp_list = list(callback_dict.keys())
    for n_id in temp_list:
        if n_id:
            callback_disable(n_id)


def draw_callback_px(n_id, data):
    space = bpy.context.space_data
    ng_view = space.edit_tree
    if not ng_view:
        return

    ng_name = space.edit_tree.name
    if not (data['tree_name'] == ng_name):
        return
    if not isinstance(ng_view, node_tree.SverchCustomTree):
        return

    face_color = (0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
    scn = bpy.context.scene
    s = scn.sv_scale_unit
    image_name = scn.sv_available_image

    img = bpy.data.images.get(image_name)
    if img:
        img.gl_load(0, bgl.GL_NEAREST, bgl.GL_NEAREST)
        texture = img.bindcode
        w, h = img.size
        w2 = w / 2
        h2 = h / 2
        _w2 = w2 * s
        _h2 = h2 * s
    else:
        return

    glEnable(GL_BLEND)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture)
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(-1.0 * _w2, -1.0 * _h2, 0.0)  # Bottom Left Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(+1.0 * _w2, -1.0 * _h2, 0.0)  # Bottom Right Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(+1.0 * _w2, +1.0 * _h2, 0.0)  # Top Right Of The Texture and Quad
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(-1.0 * _w2, +1.0 * _h2, 0.0)  # Top Left Of The Texture and
    glEnd()
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

    # restore opengl defaults
    glLineWidth(1)
    glDisable(GL_BLEND)
    glColor4f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)


def get_items(self, context):
    images = bpy.data.images
    inames = [i.name for i in images]
    return [(i, i, 'image %s' % i) for i in inames]


class svImageShowOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "scene.operator_sv_show_image_bg"
    bl_label = "Image Show"
    bl_description = "Toggle the visibility of the background image"

    # _handle = None

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        scn = context.scene
        if scn.sv_show_image and scn.sv_available_image:
            return True

    def modal(self, context, event):
        nt = context.space_data.node_tree
        if scn.sv_show_image and scn.sv_available_image:
            n_id = node_id(nt)
            callback_enable(n_id, nt)
        else:
            callback_disable_all()
            return {"CANCELLED"}

        return {"PASS_THROUGH"}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        scn = context.scene
        nt = context.space_data.node_tree

        if scn.sv_show_image and scn.sv_available_image:
            n_id = node_id(nt)
            callback_enable(n_id, nt)
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        else:
            self.report({"WARNING"}, "View3D not found, can't run operator")
            return {"CANCELLED"}


class SverchokImageBG(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "Sverchok_img_bf"
    bl_label = "SV BGIMAGE"
    bl_space_type = 'NODE_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Sverchok'
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}
    use_pin = True

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        try:
            return context.space_data.node_tree.bl_idname == 'SverchCustomTreeType'
        except:
            return False

    def draw(self, context):
        scn = context.scene
        layout = self.layout
        ntree = context.space_data.node_tree
        c = layout.column()
        c.operator(svImageShowOperator.bl_idname, text="Show Image")
        c.prop(scn, 'sv_show_image')
        c.prop(scn, 'sv_available_image', text='pick image')
        c.prop(scn, 'sv_scale_unit')


def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.sv_show_image = bpy.props.BoolProperty()
    bpy.types.Scene.sv_available_image = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name="Images", items=get_items,
        description="Image paths")
    bpy.types.Scene.sv_scale_unit = bpy.props.FloatProperty(default=1.2)

    bpy.types.Scene.sv_custom_backdrop = bpy.props.StringProperty(default='')
    bpy.utils.register_class(svImageShowOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(SverchokImageBG)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SverchokImageBG)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(svImageShowOperator)
    callback_disable_all()

    scn = bpy.types.Scene
    del scn.sv_custom_backdrop
    del scn.sv_show_image
    del scn.sv_available_image
    del scn.sv_scale_unit


if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

**Edit**

hmmm, as soon as nodes are added the texture gets broken.

- `PRE_VIEW` works nicely, but the texture at (x,y,0) is behind the grid.
- in 'POST_VIEW' adding this seems to stabilize the image

  ```
  glEnable(GL_BLEND)
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture)
  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
  glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
  glColor4f(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0)
  glBegin(GL_QUADS)
  ```

Comment: this is an amazing hack :) I've done similar stuff for rig UIs in the 3D view. In this case I'm trying to add a preview image in the node itself (similar to the preview image in e.g. image nodes. I wonder if the new preview utility can work....

Comment: I don't know to what extent bpy.utils.preview can be drawn on pynodes `draw_buttons`.. worth investigating