# Where are PyNode socket values stored?

Tags: pynodes

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how information flows through PyNodes.. Where/how should I set the value of my node's output sockets?

I've been trying to implement this in my node's update method. My idea is that I should be able to access the value of the input sockets, do something with the values, then set the value of the output sockets. My problem is that it doesn't appear that the NodeSocket class actually stores values anywhere.

1. How can I access the value in my node's input sockets?
2. Where should I implement the actual processing that my node should be responsible for?
3. How can I set the value of my node's output sockets?

Comment: check this example http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?331299-Cycles-Custom-Float-Node&p=2606082&viewfull=1#post2606082

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23430/cycles-pynode-which-outputs-objects-properties, Jacques Lucke says: `For now pynodes aren't ment to work in cycles/compositor/.. They are visually there but won't do anything. I think the script by Atom only works because it is such a simple node that does in fact nothing.` Might be better to extend _Animation Nodes_ for your needs.

Comment: Similar to what I came up [with here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14726/935)

Comment: @poor I should be able to make nodes do actual work, as long as they live in a custom node tree type, right? What I think I'm trying to head towards is wrapping some/all of the [scipy.ndimage](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html) methods, along with some input/output nodes for reading/writing numpy arrays from/to various filetypes.

Comment: My experience in this is very limited..., but maybe this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23465/how-to-add-backdrop-images-for-py-nodes/30743#30743 could be interesting in your case.